# make output is different from Makefile

Tags: g++, makefile

I have a Makefile with this content

```
$ cat Makefile
all: locality
locality: src/locality.o
    g++ src/locality.o -o locality

locality.o: src/locality.cpp
    g++ -O3  -c src/locality.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf src/*.o locality
```

However when I run `make`, I see some slightly different output!

```
$ make clean
rm -rf src/*.o locality

$ make
g++    -c -o src/locality.o src/locality.cpp
g++ src/locality.o -o locality
```

So where is `-O3`??

Comment: You're listing the dependency as `src/locality.o` but the target as `locality.o`. Is `make` realizing these are the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tripped over a built-in rule in GNU make, namely `%.o: %.c`. Use `$CFLAGS` instead.

```
CFLAGS=-O3

all: locality
locality: src/locality.o
    g++ src/locality.o -o locality

clean:
    rm -rf src/*.o locality
```

Answer (score 1):

Make is using an implicit rule to create `src/locality.o` because you have no rule for it (you only have a rule for `locality.o` in the current directory, not  in `src`.

This is what you get for violating one of [Paul's rules of Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html):

> Every non-.PHONY rule **must** update a file with the exact name of its target.

To do that, you should use `$@` in your rule to designate the target file.